# Why is there an issue in the ViewController.h?

Tags: xcode, project

I just implemented AdMob and this issue appeared. Can someone tell me why and how to fix it? Please. http://i.gyazo.com/a47ab3197d20407db09d00f6a43dbe66.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove { and } (curly braces)

```
{ // remove this bracket 
IBOutlet UILabel *HighScore;
} // remove this bracket
```

and declare your label into upper block like this

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    GADBannerView *bannerView_;
    IBOutlet UILabel *HighScore;
}
```

may this fix your problem.